# Passing parameter in ReactJS onclick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this React component that has items generated from a list (with a map function). Each of those elements has a button. I want this button's onclick button to pass in a parameter to identify which list item's button was clicked.

It looks something like this.

```
var Component = React.createClass({
    assignItem: function(item){
        this.setState({item:item})
    },
    render: function(){
        var listItems = list.map(function(item){
        return <div>{item}
        <button onClick={this.assignItem(item)>Click</button>
        </div>
        })
        return <div>{listItems}</div>
    }
})
```

Of course that doesn't work. The error message says that this.assignItem is not a function. 
I know the official React documentation suggests this:

```
var handleClick = function(i, props) {
  console.log('You clicked: ' + props.items[i]);
}

function GroceryList(props) {  
  return (
    <div>
  {props.items.map(function(item, i) {
    return (
      <div onClick={handleClick.bind(this, i, props)} key={i}>{item}</div>
    );
  })}
</div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(
   <GroceryList items={['Apple', 'Banana', 'Cranberry']} />, mountNode
);
```

but that works with a function outside of the component. Since I want my function to manipulate the sate, I want to keep it within the React component.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Original accepted answer:

You can `bind` to a function on `this` just like the React example, however since you are rendering in a `map` callback you need to either [pass in `thisArg`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) or use a fat arrow function:

```
var Component = React.createClass({
    assignItem: function(item){
        this.setState({item:item})
    },
    render: function(){
        // bind to this.assignItem
        var listItems = list.map(function(item){
            return <div>{item}
                <button onClick={this.assignItem.bind(this, item)}>Click</button>
            </div>
        }, this); // pass in this, or use fat arrow map callback
        return <div>{listItems}</div>
    }
})
```

## Update 2017:

This is an old question using an [old React API](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/04/07/react-v15.5.0.html#new-deprecation-warnings) and an accordingly old answer. Today you should be using the [class or functional React component API](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html). For passing arguments to click handlers you can just write an inline [fat arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Arrow_functions) and call through with whatever params you want. The above example ends up like this:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component { // or React.PureComponent
    assignItem = item => { // bound arrow function handler
        this.setState({ item: item });
    }
    render() {
        var listItems = list.map(item => {
            // onClick is an arrow function that calls this.assignItem
            return <div>{item}
                <button onClick={e => this.assignItem(item)}>Click</button>
            </div>
        });
        return <div>{ listItems }</div>
    }
}
```

*Note: The `assignItem` handler must be bound, which is done here using an arrow function as a [class property](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/).*

Comment: @MariePelletier, what if I am returning <a> tag, so I also need to preventDefault. How do I pass event to assignItem? Or should I just always use <button> for such cases

Comment: `bind` will prepend arguments but still pass the original arguments, so `assignItem` can take a second event arg as `function(item, event)` and call `event.preventDefault()`.